# NGINX unable to find my API path Flask Rest API

Tags: nginx, flask, amazon-ec2, deployment, gunicorn

I have developed a flask API, with the below code:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from semantic_similarity import semanticSimilarity
            
app = Flask(__name__)
            
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def health():
    return "Server is Up and Running"
            
@app.route('/semanticsimilarity', methods = ['POST'])
def get_semantic_similarity():
                
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = request.get_json()
            sent1 = data["text1"]
            sent2 = data["text2"]
            semantic_similarity_obj = semanticSimilarity(sent1, sent2)
            similarity_score = semantic_similarity_obj.score_calculations()
            response_obj = {
                            "similarity score": str(similarity_score)
            }
            return jsonify(response_obj), 200
        else:
            return {"message":"Invalid Request Method"},405
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return jsonify({"error": "Error Occured"}), 400

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I tried to deploy it to EC2 instance, It ran successfully on executing flask run, I also developed the gunicorn service which worked well. Later when I configured the Nginx proxy service, my basic home url is working but the /semanticsimilarity its unable to find.

Please find my gunicorn service code:

`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app (worked fine)`

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/semantic_similarity.service`:

```
[Unit]

Description=Gunicorn instance for a simple app
After=network.target

[Service]

User=ubuntu
Group=www-data

WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/semantic_similarity_akash1118
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/semantic_similarity_akash1118/env/bin/gunicorn -b localhost:5000 app:app
Restart=always

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl start semantic_similarity

sudo systemctl enable semantic_similarity

curl localhost:5000 (this also worked well)
```

please find the nginx config below:

```
upstream flask_semantic_similarity {server 127.0.0.1:5000;}

server {listen 80 default_server;

listen [::]:80 default_server;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://flask_semantic_similarity;
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

I use the below command:

```
sudo systemctl start nginx
sudo systemctl enable nginx
```

On going to my_ip adddress: I am getting the health status,

But as soon as I am switching to http://my_ip/semanticsimilarity

its returning:

> 404 Not Found
> `<h1>404 Not Found</h1>`
> `<hr>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)`

Comment: what does mean by 'default_server' in ngnix configuration ? try your server ip .